# Django application static file getting loaded for localhost but not for 0.0.0.0

Tags: reactjs, django

I have a django application that I am trying to run on port 0.0.0.0 but the static files are using https (I have SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT=False), the first page is loading without static files but even if I go to the next page it is forwarding to https. I ran the same application on localhost and everything works fine.

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(SITE_ROOT, 'static/')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

MIDDLEWARE = [
    # 'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
```

I have cleared the browser cache multiple times and have checked every possible stackoverflow answer, dont know why this is happening. Please help.

```
+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT) + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

For frontend I am using react js and python version is 3.7.16. Thanks.